# Ubuntu 22.04 Server fails to boot on Raspberry Pi 4: Failed to load "initrd.img"

Tags: boot, server, raspberrypi

I was using Ubuntu Server 20.04 and then tried updating it to Ubuntu 22.04. I left it overnight and in the morning I could not access it. I pulled the plug, powered it again and no boot. The EEPROM was corrupted. I reflashed the EEPROM and I was able to get this screen.

Is this recoverable? Or is there any way to get the docker container data and put it on a fresh Ubuntu Server install?

Boot error screen:

[image: Boot Error Screen]